# Is there a function that will give me the date format based on current locale

Tags: javascript, internationalization

I have toLocaleDateString that formats date based on current locale. Is there a function that will return the format based on current locale in MM/DD/YYYY format ? I want the answer to be like "MM/DD/YYYY" OR  "DD/MM/YYYY" based on the locale.

```
const options = { day: '2-digit', month: '2-digit', year: 'numeric' }
{selectedDate.toLocaleDateString(locale, options)}
```

gives me the date in the correct format based on locale

Is there something like

```
{selectedDate.toLocaleDateFormat(locale, options)}
```

that will return DD/MM/YYYY or MM/DD/YYYY or whatever the locale's format is
My codesandbox has the code

https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-benz-yzvhx

Answer (score 0):

There is no official API to give you that.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var d = new Date();
d = String(d)


var res = d.split("-");

console.log(res)

preFormat = (res[0].split(" "))

month = preFormat[1]
day = preFormat[2]
year = preFormat[3]

UsFormat = ("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec".indexOf(month) / 3 + 1) + '/' + day + '/' + year


UkFormat = day + '/' + ("JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec".indexOf(month) / 3 + 1) + '/' + year
console.log(UsFormat)
console.log(UkFormat)
```

Comment: Thanks, It is not just UK and US I want. I want the format based on current browser locale.

Comment: var d = new Date(); this should return browser local no ?

Comment: I want the format(MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYY or whatever it is) , not the date formatted based on current locale

Comment: Okay I get what you are saying...can you update your question with an expected input.

Comment: That does not work. Not all locales use "-" as date separator, so your split will fail. And of course the month names need to be localized, because the question was not about English, was "based on locale".